# java ssl handshake without downloading the certificate

Tags: java, cryptography, x509certificate

During an SSL handshake, the step 3, which is downloading the certificate from the server, is optional.

So if I have distributed the certificate with my client, how can I skip the downloading to improve the performance?

Note that I know how to load a local certificate and how to trust it. But I don't know how to skip the downloading process and I haven't found anything useful in the java document.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

My question is NOT about using a cipher suite which does not require a certificate. I still have a certificate and wish to use its public key for symmetric key exchange.

Comment: If you care about connecting to a server which does not use a certificate this is an duplicate to [How to connect to an SSL Server in Java that doesn't send a certificate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512394/how-to-connect-to-an-ssl-server-in-java-that-doesnt-send-a-certificate). If you ask about connecting to a server with a certificate but without downloading it *again* then you effectively ask about session resume which is duplicate to [Resume TLS connection in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318325/resume-tls-connection-in-java).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Actually I'm asking about connecting to a server with a certificate but without downloading it _even at the first time_. Is that possible?

Comment: Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. If you use a cipher suite which requires a certificate, a certficate is required. SSL does not use public keys for encryption except in one case of a handshake message. Your question therefore doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP I might have not made it clear. I wish to use something like pre-shared public key. I wish a cipher suite which requires a certificate, but I also want to get the certificate from local instead of from online server.

Comment: The certificate in an SSL cipher suite performs an authentication function, not an encryption function, and it is delivered over the wire. Otherwise it cannot perform that function. A cipher suite that requires a certificate but doesn't use it for authentication and doesn't get it over the wire is therefore a contradiction in terms. What you are describing is not SSL at all, nor anything else that I can see.

Comment: @EJP Please see my last comment at the answer below.

Comment: This is still making zero sense. SSL already does symmetric key *negotiation*, and *without* an exchange, which makes it much more secure than what you are proposing, which isn't SSL at all in any way shape or form.

Comment: @EJP You can't persuade me here. We can also make use of a local certificate and _negotiate_. It does not make much difference. My proposal can be as same secure hereby. You have shown me that the standard enforces the downloading if a cipher suite with certificate is used, which is good to know. But what I'm wondering now is why. I guess that I can't understand it without fully studying the SSL.

Comment: You can do whatever you like, but you can't call the result SSL unless it complies with RFC 2246, and this doesn't. You also can't use Java's JSSE library to accomplish it, as that's not what it's for. NB I'm not attempting to 'persuade' you. I'm *telling* you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is NOT about using a cipher suite which does not require a certificate. I still have a certificate and wish to use its public key for encryption.

I think you are missing the role of a certificate in TLS. The main task is to provide authentication so that the connection is protected against man in the middle attacks (i.e. man in the middle claiming to be the server).

Payload encryption is not done by the certificate at all. At most it is used to exchange the encryption key in RSA based key exchange. But for currently recommended key exchanges (ECDHE and maybe DHE) the certificate is not needed at all.

Which means that using a certificate only for key exchange but not for authentication makes no sense and for this reason there is no cipher which supports this.

Comment: Actually I do use the certificate for authentication. But the certificate is given as local file, through offline delivery. I think it makes sense to have a certificate here.

Comment: @Immueggpain A certificate that is provided as a local file instead of over the wire cannot possibly constitute part of any conceivable online peer authentication process. You aren't making any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @Immueggpain: Authentication is not only that the client knows which certificate to expect but that the server proves that it owns this certificate, i.e. that the server has the private key. There is no support in TLS for doing that prove without also sending the certificate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think the problem is I don't know much about the TLS. So I thought that there's something like a switch to turn off the certificate transfer. But one thing still confuses me. You said that there's no way that server proves that it owns this certificate. But I thought that if the handshake succeeds then the server must own the private key otherwise the TLS handshake would fail thus indicating that the server may be a fake.

Comment: Exactly, *when the certificate is delivered via the SSL handshake.* Itf it is acquired locally there is no proof possible.

Comment: I'm still unable to understand why the local and on-the-wire would make a difference. Suppose that we have a perfectly standard SSL handshake, then replace the step 3 with a local certificate, why would this be impossible? If the server is a fake then at step 8 _client key exchange_, the server won't be able to decrypt the key for symmetric encryption. And if the server really _owns_ the certificate, then the process can go on without any exception. I really don't see any difference here. And I can save some traffic.

Comment: I have edited my question to show that public key is used for symmetric key exchange.

Comment: On the wire the server has to send a signature over its certificate signed by its private key. This is the step that assures the client that the server owns that certificate. This is not the place to explain to you how SSL works if you don't already know.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for your patience. I indeed not understand much about how SSL works and why it works the way it does. I would accept the answer _that's what the standard says_ and go learning SSL in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

> During an SSL handshake, the step 3, which is downloading the certificate from the server, is optional.

I don't know where you get your step numbers from, but sending the server certificate is mandatory unless the client states in the `ClientHello` message that it will accept a non-authenticating cipher suite, and this is specifically described in RFC 2246 as insecure.

> So if I have distributed the certificate with my client, how can I skip the downloading to improve the performance?

You can't.

> Note that I know how to load a local certificate and how to trust it. But I don't know how to skip the downloading process and I haven't found anything useful in the java document.

Of course you haven't found it. It isn't there. There isn't anything about it at all in the Java documentation, or RFC 2246 either. You've invented this requirement. That doesn't mean that either Java JSSE or SSL itself supports it. It doesn't.

> My question is NOT about using a cipher suite which does not require a certificate. I still have a certificate and wish to use its public key for symmetric key exchange.

SSL does not perform symmetric key exchange. Once again you are talking about something that doesn't exist. If you want to understand SSL, read RFC 2246. If you want to invent your own, feel free, but don't call it SSL, and don't kid yourself that it will be either as performant or as secure as SSL, which has had nearly 25 years of development. It won't.

Comment: I have just read RFC5246 section 7.4.2. Although that _The server MUST send a Certificate message whenever the agreed-upon key exchange method uses certificates for authentication_. But the message's definition is _ASN.1Cert certificate_list<0..2^24-1>;_. Well, if I understand it right then I can send NO certificate and call it SSL(I suppose we are talking SSL/TLS here, after all they are just different versions of the same thing). Maybe you are referencing some outdated materials?